# How to select a layer in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop, if you choose `View > Show > Layer Edges`, a blue border will appear around the currently-selected layer. Is there a way to make the marquee tool select that exact area? I know I can command-click on the layer thumbnail to select all visible pixels in the layer, but is there a way to quickly get a rectangular selection that matches the layer boundaries, or do I need to manually drag the rectangular marquee tool to match the layer boundary that Photoshop is showing me?

Comment: No inherent way I know of. Certainly no existing command or shortcut. With scripting it should be possible.

Comment: Do you mean selecting the entire canvas? Maybe try cmd + A.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "simple" way to do this out of the box, but if you want to select the area to copy you can make an action script with:

- Trim (Transparent pixels - same as showing boundaries of the content in the layer)
- Select All
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for merged copy, or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for content in the current layer.
- Revert back to before Trimming.

I created an action for you with these steps. It can be downloaded from here:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/f3nh0n

(remember to perform virus check on files you receive by from strangers such as a me).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need to do, I do this very often to copy a layer to a new document cropped to bounding pixels:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the 'eye' of a layer to solo it.
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>(command or control) to select all
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy everything
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create new document, it will automatically create it at
  the right size
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste

Done.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on the layer in the layers panel.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as mentioned in my question, command-clicking in the layer only selects "visible pixels", not the entire rectangle of the layer boundary.

Comment: Sorry, missed that in my haste. That sounds like something for javascript, if this is something you want to do more than once.